# Does $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=1$ imply that $a_n$ convergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Does the condition $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=1$ imply that $a_n$ convergent?

When I say convergent I mean to $L\in \mathbb{R}$ or to $\infty$ or to $-\infty$

I have a gut feeling this statement is false, just can't find a series which contradicts it.

Thanks a lot

Comment: @Plopperzz It goes to infinity.

Comment: It goes to infinity.. read the first line in my question

Comment: Here is a counter-example: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3015738/42969.

Comment: Ok great Martin this a fine contradiction! I am happy my gut feeling didn't disappoint me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A counter-example is $a_ n = 2 + \sin(\log(n))$ which is not convergent (it oscillates between $1$ and $3$). But
$$
 \left\lvert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} - 1 \right\rvert 
= \left\lvert \frac{\sin(\log(n+1))- \sin(\log(n))}{2 + \sin(\log(n))} \right\rvert \\
\le \left\lvert \sin(\log(n+1))- \sin(\log(n)) \right\rvert 
= \left\lvert \frac{\cos(\log(x_n))}{x_n}\right\rvert 
$$
for some $x_n \in (n, n+1)$, using the mean value theorem. It follows that
$$
\left\lvert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} - 1 \right\rvert \le \frac{1}{n} \to 0 \, ,
$$
i.e. $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \to 1$.

Roughly speaking, $(a_n)$ oscillates, but with decreasing frequency,
so that the ratio of successive sequence elements approaches one.

(This example is taken from [$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} = 1 \Rightarrow \exists c \in \mathbb{R}: \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} {a_n} = c$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3015009/lim-limits-n-to-infty-fraca-na-n1-1-rightarrow-exists-c-in-m/3015738#3015738). I copied it here because the other question excludes sequences converging to $\pm \infty$, so it is not an exact duplicate.)

Answer (score 3):

A counterexample: $a_n = \exp(\sin\sqrt{n})$. The ratio $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ is
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\exp(\sin(\sqrt{n+1})-\sin(\sqrt{n}))\approx \exp\frac{\cos(\sqrt{n})}{2\sqrt{n}}\approx 1+\frac{\cos(\sqrt{n})}{2\sqrt{n}}\to 1$$
but $a_n$ oscillates between $e^1$ and $e^{-1}$, not converging to anything or diverging to $\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Think to a sequence $(a_n)$ such that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (a_{n+1}-a_n)=0$, but that oscillates infinitely between $1$ and $2$.

The limit points of $(a_n)$ is the segment $[1,2]$ and $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=1$.

Some examples [here](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/counterexamples-on-real-sequences-part-2/) and [there](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/counterexamples-on-real-sequences-part-3/).